# Using a Ruby workflow using Bootstrap w/ SASS to generate a static website

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am currently building a small 'About Me' page for myself using bootstrap. I am using the compiled version of bootstrap, but I want to use the version you can install with 'gem install bootstrap-sass.'

For my normal web work I have set up my own environment which uses Makefiles to build the website from a raw version to a distributable version.

I want the same using bootstrap-sass gem. I do not want to use Ruby on Rails.

Can someone provide me with a rough set of actions or a tutorial on the web where this issue is explained?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/), and following the solution [in this github issue documenting using bootstrap-sass with middleman](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/948).